# How do you stop a single-page site from automatically scrolling when resizing the browser?

Tags: html, css

So basically I have a single page website im working on and have progressed so far till i met this stupid/annoying bug. The top page doesn't automatically scroll when you resize it but the others do: Heres my css

```
 body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* look this up */
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    height: 100%;
}


.mainPage {
float:left;
height:100%;
width:100%;

background: url(Imgs/13.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;


/*
background-size:100%;
background-position: center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
*/

}

.projectContents {

float:left;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background: white;

}

.musicContent {

float:left;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background: url(Imgs/10.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;


}
```

My html:

```
<section id = "mainPage" class="container mainPage" >
</section>

<section id = "projectContents" class = "container projectContents" >
</section>

<section  id = "musicContent" class="container musicContent" >
</section>
```

When you scroll down to the last page and try to resize it, it automatically scrolls the page up, how do you fix this? Thank you a bunch!!!

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question so that it might be understandable - thanks! A (web) page is a page. And you have different sections on your page. Each should be 100% width and height (so why floating them)? So what is exactly your problem when resizing the viewport? And what would you like to achieve?

Comment: @Netsurfer Basically its a one-page website with 3 sections, when you navigate to the last section(bottom page) and resize the browser to a smaller screen its fine but when you scroll it back to the original( or increasing the browser) the page automatically scrolls up to the middle of the webpage (weird) My question is that how do i make sure when i'm resizing it back to the original size it should still be on the same section instead of half of it(due to the automatic scrolling up).

Comment: I guess this happens due to the elements heights aren't actually updated on window resize. Does this happen in any browser, or only in Safari? BTW: Try removing the (unnecessary) float and see if it still happens!

Comment: @Netsurfer happens in both chrome and safari :(

Comment: Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k8uTU/)

Comment: @Netsurfer does exactly the same thing as my website !

Comment: Try the updated [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k8uTU/2/) - in Chrome for Windows I cannot reproduce this behaviour. The small shift is caused by the header on jsfiddle.net! But also don't worry - users normally do not resize their browser window! This only developers do ...! ;-)

Comment: @Netsurfer Haha Fair Enough ;)

Comment: @Netsurfer Just tried it on windows, still the same but Thanks alot though ill live it as it is and figure it out later ;)

Comment: With which browser? Maybe you could post the link to a screen shot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding the issue in the comments (on the question) I'll add it also as an answer, so anybody could easily find it.

Safari (and Chrome) for Mac/ iOS seem to have "difficulties" with repainting/ redrawing the page.

One way to "solve" this issue is to use a JS event handler on the windows's resize event.
This handler then calls a function which adds and remove a style attribute on the elements that need to be repainted.

It is absolutely vital to use the style attribut. On all other methods the elements aren't repainted!

Here is the JS code (using jQuery):

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', triggerRepaint, false);
}

function triggerRepaint() {
    $('.container).attr('style', 'display:none;').attr('style', 'display:block;');
}
```

See the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k8uTU/2/)

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 1):

When I try it doesn't though a way to solve this would be with javascript or jquery:

```
var doc = document.documentElement, body = document.body;
var top = (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0);
document.resize = function() {
    top = (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0);
    left = (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0)
    window.scrollTo(left, top);
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/4maDV/)

Comment: what kind of scrolling do you mean and what computer and browser are you on

Comment: when i resize it(to be smaller) its fine but when i try resizing it back to full screen, it automatically scrolls the page up

Comment: im using a The new retina mac book pro and i use chrome mostly than safari. other pages like mine seems to be fine but mine messes up